# How to filter array by the key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need filter array by bookmakers.key === 'bovada'. I need data on this. This question is important to me for studing arrays.

```
const array = [
    {
        "id": "9ee1340b779938f9a7f829f22d41534d",
        "sport_key": "soccer_argentina_primera_division",
        "sport_title": "Primera División - Argentina",
        "commence_time": "2023-03-30T23:00:00Z",
        "home_team": "Defensa y Justicia",
        "away_team": "Velez Sarsfield BA",
        "bookmakers": [
            {
                "key": "foxbet",
                "title": "FOX Bet",
                "last_update": "2023-03-30T14:01:13Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "last_update": "2023-03-30T14:01:13Z",
                         "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Argentinos Juniors",
                                "price": 1.74
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Godoy Cruz",
                                "price": 5.4
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Draw",
                                "price": 3.25
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "bovada",
                "title": "Bovada",
                "last_update": "2023-03-30T13:58:23Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "last_update": "2023-03-30T13:58:23Z",
                         "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Argentinos Juniors",
                                "price": 1.74
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Godoy Cruz",
                                "price": 5.4
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Draw",
                                "price": 3.25
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6253cf45de6b5050c44505812e12f5fd",
        "sport_key": "soccer_argentina_primera_division",
        "sport_title": "Primera División - Argentina",
        "commence_time": "2023-03-31T00:30:00Z",
        "home_team": "Argentinos Juniors",
        "away_team": "Godoy Cruz",
        "bookmakers": [
            {
                "key": "foxbet",
                "title": "FOX Bet",
                "last_update": "2023-03-30T14:01:13Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "last_update": "2023-03-30T14:01:13Z",
                         "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Argentinos Juniors",
                                "price": 1.74
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Godoy Cruz",
                                "price": 5.4
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Draw",
                                "price": 3.25
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "bovada",
                "title": "Bovada",
                "last_update": "2023-03-30T13:58:23Z",
                "markets": [
                    {
                        "key": "h2h",
                        "last_update": "2023-03-30T13:58:23Z",
                        "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Argentinos Juniors",
                                "price": 1.74
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Godoy Cruz",
                                "price": 5.4
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Draw",
                                "price": 3.25
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "spreads",
                        "last_update": "2023-03-30T13:58:23Z",
                        "outcomes": [
                            {
                                "name": "Argentinos Juniors",
                                "price": 1.95,
                                "point": -0.75
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Godoy Cruz",
                                "price": 1.87,
                                "point": 0.75
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I expected get the array without foxbet information. I can only filter simple arrays. I can't filter this array for two days now...

I tried array.filter(i => i.bookmakers.filter(k => k.key === "bovada")) but, no.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to filter array of arrays by the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889520/how-to-filter-array-of-arrays-by-the-key)

Comment: @AndrewParks you can't call this a duplicate of a closed question; that doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Rojo it's exactly the same question copy-and-pasted again, without addressing the reason the original question was closed

Comment: You must `i.bookmakers` is an array; you must index that array in your filter function

Comment: @AndrewParks I see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const result = array.filter((arr) => {
  let newBookmaker = arr.bookmakers.filter(
    (bookmaker) => bookmaker.key == "bovada"
  );
  if (newBookmaker.length > 0) {
    arr.bookmakers = newBookmaker;
    return arr;
  }
});
```